# Ninject creates singleton instance multiple times on domain event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design, ninject

**Domain Service**

```
public void MyDomainService {

    void DoSomething() {
        Raise<MyDomainEvent>(new DomainEvent());
    }

}
```

**Singleton Application Service**

```
public void SingletonApplicationService {
    // Handles MyDomainEvent

    private int _myRandomId = new RandomId();

    public SingletonApplicationService() {
        _logger.Info("Hello, I'm " + _myRandomId + ". I got resolved.");
    }

    public void Handle(DomainEvent event) {
        _logger.Info("Hello, I'm " + _myRandomId + ". I received a domain event.");
    }

}
```

**Kernel Bindings**

```
Kernel.Bind<IDomainService>().To<DomainService>()
    .InRequestScope();
Kernel.Bind<ISingletonApplicationService>()
    .To<SingletonApplicationService>()
    .InSingletonScope();
Kernel.Bind<IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>>()
    .To<SingletonApplicationService>();
     // tried as singleton and per request
```

**Application Startup**

```
Kernel.Get<ISingletonApplicationService>();

var domainService = Kernel.Get<IDomainService>();
domainService.DoSomething();
```

This produces the following log:

```
"Hello, I'm 421. I got resolved."
// domain event occurs here
"Hello, I'm 455. I got resolved."
"Hello, I'm 421. I received a domain event.");
"Hello, I'm 455. I received a domain event."); // and I crash because of that!
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Ninject, you also need to register the `IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>` to have singleton scope, [as default scope is transient](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).

```
Kernel.Bind<IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>>()
    .To<SingletonApplicationService>()
    .InSingletonScope();
```

I believe however that you will have a singleton instance per service i.e. a singleton instance for an `ISingletonApplicationService` and a singleton instance for `IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>`. You may want both to resolve to the same singleton instance. One way of achieving this and have lazy instantiation would be

```
Kernel.Bind<SingletonApplicationService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Kernel.Bind<ISingletonApplicationService >().ToMethod(
    c => c.Kernel.Get<SingletonApplicationService>());
Kernel.Bind<IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>>().ToMethod(
    c => c.Kernel.Get<SingletonApplicationService>());
```

Comment: I alreay tried that, but with no luck. This was also my first guess. :/

Comment: How does `SingletonApplicationService` implement `IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>`?

Comment: How do you mean 'how'? I have an interface ISingletonApplicationScope which implements IDomainEventHandler<MyDomainEvent>().

Comment: @Acrotygma Ok, but you don't show that in your question, nor do you show what implements `ISingletonApplicationScope`

Comment: You are a god and I praise you! Are there any downsides with resolving an interface to a method?

Comment: Not really. Instead of constructing an instance by calling its constructor, Ninject container will call the passed method which in turn is going to resolve to another component registered with the container (which in turn the container will construct by calling its constructor). You could see it as a layer of indirection and have the most negligible permformance overhead compared to the container instantiating with a constructor directly. I wouldn't see this as a concern; you are using an IoC container after all :)